# PayPal Order Summary Using REST API - - cURL or PHP

Tags: php, rest, curl, paypal

I am working with the PayPal RESTful API.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

How can I pass my consumers order items and purchase description to PayPal, so when my user is redirected to PayPal to approve the order by logging in, their order summary will show up on the left.
 .

.

**ORDER SUMMARY ON THE LEFT**
[image: paypal empty order summary]

I have tried to passing in the transactions.item_list.items but that information isn't showing up in the order summary still.

Any help how to get an order summary to appear on the paypal approval page using the PayPal RESTful API?

I haven't been to pleased with their documentation as it is lacking some information and also has a few mistakes which wasted decent amount of my time to debug.

```
//
// prepare paypal data
$payment = array(
            'intent' => 'sale',
            'redirect_urls' => array(
                'return_url' => $url_success,
                'cancel_url' => $url_cancel,
                ),
            'payer' => array(
                'payment_method' => 'paypal'
                )
          );

//
// prepare basic payment details
$payment['transactions'][0] = array(
                            'amount' => array(
                                'total' => '0.03',
                                'currency' => 'USD',
                                'details' => array(
                                    'subtotal' => '0.02',
                                    'tax' => '0.00',
                                    'shipping' => '0.01'
                                    )
                                ),
                            'description' => 'This is the payment transaction description 1.'
                           );

//
// prepare individual items
$payment['transactions'][0]['item_list']['items'][] = array(
                                        'quantity' => '1',
                                        'name' => 'Womens Large',
                                        'price' => '0.01',
                                        'currency' => 'USD',
                                        'sku' => '31Wf'
                                       );
$payment['transactions'][0]['item_list']['items'][] = array(
                                        'quantity' => '1',
                                        'name' => 'Womens Medium',
                                        'price' => '0.01',
                                        'currency' => 'USD',
                                        'sku' => '31WfW'
                                       );

//
//format payment array to pass to cURL
$CURL_POST = json_encode($payment);
```

Comment: Can you post a code sample so we can see how you are building the API call?

Comment: there is a simple example, I am using cURL to process the PayPal payments.  Everything else is working fine, Access Token, Create/Execute Payments ... I just can't get my shopping cart to show up in the order summary section using the RESTful API

Answer (score 1):

your code is good. This is actually a bug that will be fixed very soon. Regarding documentation, can you share how we can make it better? I want to make sure your feedback gets passed to our documentation team.

Comment: First, I would make sure you specify in your documentation that you need to pass in your client id and secret key with every cURL call.  Not just the call to get an access token.

Comment: The successful paypal redirect... your documentation states that you are passing back "payer_id" ... you are actually passing back "PayerID"

Comment: Another issues... the ITEM object within the TRANSACTION object, says that SKU is optional field, but it is really required by your api.  Also, when things are successfully returned, the ITEM.SKU replaces the ITEM.NAME value that I passed.

Comment: you don't need to make client_id and secret with every curl call, only when you get an access token. after that you pass access token in teach call. Do you have an example where this did not work for you?

Comment: can you help me locate where in the docs we say that we pass back "payer_id"? I found this "client_id string The ID of the Payer, passed in the return_url by PayPal. Required". Is this what you are referring to? It is true that PayerID is what we sent back in the returnURL, but in the REST call you need to pass "payer_id"

Comment: That is what I thought too about the client id and secret key.  I tried for almost an hour to create a payment just using the access token.  I wasn't getting any kind of return or error message so I decided I would include the client id and secret again, once I did, it worked perfectly

Comment: Here is the link to execute a paypal payment. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/#execute-the-payment  you will see that it says the return url passes back the "payer_id"

Comment: WHen is your release cycle.  I feel that I need to use PayPal because it is so popular but there are so many minor issues that I have had to change in my code to make things work that now I need to make sure what I have doesn't affect my sales down the road.  When should I be testing a paypal order out, every monday night?? every thursday??.  Do you have a release cycle?

Comment: Has the PayPal bug been fixed yet - should item descriptions appear in the order summary?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue while trying it out today. What I did was add the Items like below.

```
$item = new Item();
$item->setQuantity($item_quantity);
$item->setName($item_name);
$item->setPrice($item_price);
$item->setCurrency($item_currency);

$item_list = new ItemList();
$item_list->setItems(array($item));
```

The $item_list is a property of transaction so you should add it after.

```
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setItemList($item_list);
....
```

That should show on the Order summary pane on PayPal page.
You can also check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885742/pay-with-paypal-through-paypal-rest-api-does-not-show-up-payment-description-on?rq=1).

Comment: How can i do the same thing in billing plan (recurring payments)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sample shown here : http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/master/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

It is a sample that comes along with the PayPal REST API SDK. You can try those samples out yourselves, by following instructions on readme.

This is how it would look like, when you run that sample:

[image]