# Cannot send multiple product items to paypal plugin using phonegap

Tags: cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins

Am trying to integrate  [PayPal plugin for PhoneGap in ios](https://github.com/SnareChops/PayPalPlugin) where with the plugin we can send only one product to the Paypal (standard PayPal checkout). I cannot send multiple product items to that Paypal Plugin.

Can anyone suggest me how to send multiple products/items using this plugin or an alternative way to achieve this using PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it does not seem to be possible out of the box, to send multiple items to PayPal with the newer iOS plugin either: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK-PhoneGap.

I have come across another answer that may be helpful in showing that **it is indeed possible to send multiple items to the new PayPal REST API, using** the **correct JSON object format** as listed in that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15893583/2728686

The mentioned plugins will need to be adapted ('hacked' or 'customized') to cater for sending multiple items to the new REST API, under the `transactions[0]['item_list']`, as showcased in the answer linked to above.

Comment: The new Android SDK plugin for Phonegap (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) also does not allow for sending multiple items to the new REST API out of the box.